# using PFQueryTableViewController as detailviewController of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I got UITableView with 8 TextLabel as AlbumName(displaying from Array),now I want to use that 'selected album name' as Parse Class name(using initWithCoder method),and display corresponding class value should be retrived as ParseTableView Rows. i did as this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailAlbum"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


    MyParseTableViewController *detailScreen =segue.destinationViewController;

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    detailScreen.className = cell.textLabel.text;

      NSLog(@"Selected Label :%@",detailScreen.className);

}
```

}

and in PFQueryTableViewController.h

```
@interface MyParseTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *className;
@end
```

PFQueryTableViewController.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
```

{

```
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self)
{

    self.parseClassName = self.className;//showing NULL here

    NSLog(@"parse Class Name1%@",self.parseClassName);


    self.textKey = @"songTitle";

    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    self.paginationEnabled = NO;
}
return self;
```

}

when I run,I get this:
 Selected Label : XYZ  <-----getting class name here,then why not passing as Parse classname
 parse Class Name1(null)<--------

QUERY:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: classname)'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS crashing when receiving empty array from Parse.com's CloudCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838591/ios-crashing-when-receiving-empty-array-from-parse-coms-cloudcode)

Comment: I think its different scenario, its definitely not Duplicated.

Comment: The answer is the same--you cannot insert `nil` into a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your app is crashing is because you are trying to insert a `nil` value into an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. Instead, you need to insert `[NSNull null]`.

Now, `NSLog(@"parse Class Name1%@",self.parseClassName);` is printing that `self.parseClassName` is NULL because `self.className` is `nil`

`-initWithCoder:` is the first method called, and the object hasn't been instantiated yet. This means that `self.className` will return `nil`. To retrieve a value from a previously coded object, you need to do something like:

```
self.parseClassName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"className"];
```

Comment: I would not know class name till user select row in first table view, and then after that selection i will be able to pass 'selected row lable as classname' in coder method..... how should i implement this???

Answer (score 0):

I think i found working answer, what i did is instead of passing 'selected classname' to -initWithCode method, i passed straight into -queryForTable method,which is working fine, i am now able to retrieve corresponding class values from Parse.
But In -initWithCoder method still showing 'Classname' as Null(as its instantiated early then user selection of TableView row) ,but i think its still working without using it.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
self.parseClassName = self.className;

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];//<---className from selected row
NSLog(@"QUERY: %@ ",query);
return query;
 }
```